# How to find out destination of a golang channel

Tags: go

I am taking over maintenance of a multi-file golang program and now trying to understand the code flow. One feature of golang is the use of channels for sending values to another part of the code base. This feature can make tracing and understanding the code flow difficult, as the execution will resume at the receiving end of the channel, which may well be in a different file and may have a different name.

When reading through the code, I can see where data is being sent to a channel, but I do not see an intuitive or easy way to figure out where it is being received.

Is there a way in gloang to find out where (as in filename:linenum) a data sent through a channel is received?

Comment: [guru](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru) can identify the other end(s) of a channel (called peers). Many IDEs and editors can integrate guru to tell you all sorts of things about Go code. See if integration is available for your editor of choice.

Comment: Wondering why the downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because multiple places can receive from the same channel, and multiple instances of the same function can be receiving from different channels. Your best bet is to follow the channel itself around - look at where it's created, then what it gets passed to, and find what is receiving from it that way.